# Can I use this approach so I can sniff both TX and RX signals using a Second arduino?

Tags: serial, usb

Based upon this [answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/90460/43808) I can hook up 2 arduinos like this:

[image: 2 arduinos that the second one is used as debug serial port]

But AFAIK The main microcontroller uses an RS232 protocol and AtMegau16 (or ATMegau8) converts it into USB one emulating an FTDI chip.

But in my case, I need just the RX port from the second in order to just sniff data. So I looked on how I can pirate the RS232 signal and I found this schematic:

[image: An rs232 spy cable]

Resulting to this monstrocity:

[image]

But would this allow me the secoind UNO to capture both RX AND TX signals?

Comment: You only need the diode on the TX line, and you only need the resistor on the RX line.

Comment: You can try this, but your sniffer will only work satisfyingly if the communication protocol is half-duplex. This means, that TX and RX are never transmitting _at the same time_. If the protocol is full-duplex, and both wires transmit at the same time, their signals are mixed together, resulting in erroneous data. To tackle this situation, you need _two_ serial receiver channels, one for TX and one for RX.

Answer (score 0):

This approach may work in some cases but will not work in all cases.

Assuming the intent is to listen to both the transmit and the receive side of an [RS232](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-232) type signal.

[An RS232 signal may swing from -12 to +12 Volts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-232#Voltage_levels).  Many logic inputs behave unexpectedly when driven by voltages higher than their supply rail.  A resistor may mitigate this problem.  A [logic level shifter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_shifter) would be better.

The circuit diagram in the question is an example of a [wired OR connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wired_logic_connection#The_wired_OR_connection).  If either serial transmit line is high the data from the other will be blocked.  As illustrated in this diagram from wikipedia.org.

[image]

So this circuit diagram will only work reliably for [half duplex communications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duplex_(telecommunications)).  If full duplex monitoring is required, two independent receivers / monitors will have to be used.